# Find the first occurrence of element from array in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, find-occurrences

I'm curious if there is a good way to find the first occurrence of element from array in another array.
As result, the answer should be a null (if no elements from the first array in the second array) or this element.
Ex.1:

```
fromArr = ["Yellow", "Green", "Orange", "Apple", "Banana", "Apple"];
whereArr= ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Apple"];
```

//the answer should be "Orange", as the order counts (first we check for "Yellow", then for "Green", then for "Orange" - occurrence found!).

Ex.2:

```
fromArr = ["Orange", "Apple", "Banana", "Apple"];
whereArr= ["November", "December", "April", "Banana"];
```

//the answer should be "Banana".

Ex.3:

```
fromArr = ["Orange", "Apple"];
whereArr= ["November", "December", "April"];
```

//the answer should be null.

Thank you

Comment: Do you need `null` or will `undefined` be fine if no item can be found?

Comment: Am I missing something? `fromArr.forEach(item => console.log(whereArr.find(item2 => item === item2)))`

Comment: Did one of these answers solve your problem? If not, could you provide more information to help answer it? Otherwise, please consider marking the answer which best solved your problem accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) on your `fromArr`, and convert your `whereArr` to a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to allow for efficient (sublinear) lookup. `.find()` will loop through all your values in `fromArr` until the callback returns `true`. Once the callback returns `true`, `.find()` will return the value you're currently iterated on. You can check if the set has the value by using [`.has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has), which will return true when a value is within the set. If find's callback doesn't return true for any values inside your fromArr, it will result in `undefined`.

See example below:

```js
const fromArr = ["Yellow", "Green", "Orange", "Apple", "Banana", "Apple"];
const whereSet = new Set(["Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Apple"]);

const result = fromArr.find(val => whereSet.has(val));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily by using "find" on the "fromArr" Array and compare if an entry is included within the "whereArr" Array.

Example:

```
fromArr = ["Yellow", "Green", "Orange", "Apple", "Banana", "Apple"];
whereArr = ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Apple"];
fromArr.find(e => whereArr.includes(e));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make an object with the index number of the items of `fromArr`. Then check the every element of `whereArr` array and which item has the smallest index(from the hash) value this is the first occurence. This method takes `O(n+m)` time.

```js
function getFirstOccurance(fromArr, whereArr) {
  const indics = fromArr.reduce((acc, curr, i) => ({...acc, [curr]: i}), {});

  let min = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
  let res = null;
  whereArr.forEach(item => {
    if (indics[item] < min) {
      min = indics[item];
      res = item;
    }
  });

  return res;
}

let arr = ["Yellow", "Green", "Orange", "Apple", "Banana", "Apple"];
let arr2= ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Apple"];
console.log(getFirstOccurance(arr, arr2));

arr = ["Orange", "Apple", "Banana", "Apple"];
arr2 = ["November", "December", "April", "Banana"];
console.log(getFirstOccurance(arr, arr2));

arr = ["Orange", "Apple"];
arr2= ["November", "December", "April"];
console.log(getFirstOccurance(arr, arr2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%; top: 0}
```